# Directive to load data from service, present it with select and bind to model with ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I'm stuck creating a 'countries' directive which load data from a service, shows a list of countries in a select control and allow to bind the selected country to a model with ng-model:

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4hg4cu9p/1

The view:

```
<div ng-controller: 'personCtrl'>
    <countries ng-model='birthCountry'/>
</div>
```

The code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])

app.controller('personCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.birthCountry = 'CO';
}]);

app.service('Country', [
  '$http', function($http) {
    return {
      list: function() {
      return $http.get('http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/region/americas', {cache: true});
      }
    };
  }]);

app.directive('countries', [
  'Country', '$log', function(Country, $log) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: "<select data-ng-model='selectedValue' data-ng-options='country.name for country in countries track by country.alpha2Code'></select?",
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        Country.list().then(function(countries) {
          scope.countries = countries.data;
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

I want to use the `ngModelController` to:
1.- Set the country in select control when model `birthCountry` changes.
2.- Change the model `birthCountry` when user change the select control.

The model is saving the birthCountry as ISO code ('CO' = Colombia, 'US' = United States)

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4hg4cu9p/1

UPDATE:
Thanks to @PSL and @apairet, here is the jsfiddle working:
http://jsfiddle.net/4hg4cu9p/3/

Comment: What is not working? could you setup a plunkr or jsfiddle?

Comment: The directive only get the countries from service. I can't get how to select the current model value on the directive select control neither returns the selected value to the object bind with ng-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are specifying `ng-model` at the directive node, do no specify it at the template instead just use `replace:true` option in the directive so ng-model will be applied automatically.

Try

```
{
  restrict: 'E',
  replace:true,
  template: "<select data-ng-options='country.alpha2Code as country.name for country in countries'></select>",
  require: 'ngModel',
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LUXa0h?p=preview)**

Comment: @AA. You are welcome. I believe in using ngModel as much as possibly and where ever possible. :) If you use 2-way binding it does not provide you as much feature an ngModelController would give, Validation/formatters etc.. is a great example for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/zw5vfjkkESJ78ypCWggi

1. use an **isolated scope**, to avoid collision between different instances of your directive
2. while not strictly required (see http://plnkr.co/edit/e9Vs8AwK5Aqx2G4ZmYVw), I prefer not to use `ngModel` as custom attribute of a directive --> use of 'my-model'. **UPDATE** Following your comment and the answer of @PSL, here is another plunker using `ng-model` and the directive option `replace: true` http://plnkr.co/edit/YVp6CauBWg3sMLrjwoQL
3. I bound the model to `country.alpha2Code` so Colombia is selected

The JS has been modified like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('personCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.birthCountry = 'CO';
}]);

app.service('Country', [
    '$http', function($http) {
        return {
            list: function() {
                return $http.get('http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/region/americas', {cache: true});
            }
        };
    }]);

app.directive('countries', [
    'Country', '$log', function(Country, $log) {
        return {
            scope: {
                myModel: '='
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<select ng-model='myModel' data-ng-options='country.alpha2Code as country.name for country in countries' track by country.alpha2Code'></select>",
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log('I am called');
                Country.list().then(function(countries) {
                    console.log(countries);
                    scope.countries = countries.data;
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
```

and your markup:

```
<div ng-controller="personCtrl">
  <countries my-model="birthCountry"></countries>

  {{birthCountry}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @apairet but why not to use `ngModelController`? It is not the standard way to bind things on angular?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am saying it is better not to use the name 'ng-model' for a custom attribute. As pointed out by @PSL, you can use 'ng-model ' and `replace: true` to have it automatically applied.  I will add another plunkr to the answer to show you how